# Program that reads a txt file, outputting it as a scrolling text

Tags: c++

I would like to create a program in C++ that opens and read a txt file (like, for example, a poem) and it then outputs it on the bottom part of the screen, in a scrolling way (to say: like the breaking news).

I thought I would start with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
ifstream infile;
infile.open("POEM.txt", ios::in);

if (!infile)
{
   cout<<"File does not exist";
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
std::string text_from file;
while (getline(infile, text_from_file))
{
   cout << text_from_file << "\n";
}

cout << "Paused. Press enter to continue.\n"
cin.ignore(10000, '\n');

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What I am not able to do is the scrolling text part.

Comment: You are operating at a terminal window, doesn't that support scrolling already?

Comment: "marquee" may be a good description for horizontally scrolling text

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Say I am opening the lyrics of a song: I would like the program to output it as a scrolling text, appearing at the bottom right of the screen, scrolling from right to the left, and disappearing to the left...

Comment: Have you looked into [ncurses](http://www.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~hughm/os/notes/ncurses.html)?